# Asking question on salesforce community?

Tags: community, chatter-answers

I am trying to post question in salesforce community but i am unable to see ask question link on answer tab. So can anyone help me. Its urgent because i am unable to login  in sandbox after refreshing.
[image]

Comment: u need to either raise a case to salesforce or get anyone else with admin access in your company to check your account in the sandbox

Comment: In what community are you trying to ask the question, your company's regular org, your sandbox, Salesforce.Success or someplace else? Are you an admin? I find your question confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong place.

That is the chatter answers overview on YOUR chatter PROFILE. That page will only show answers made by you, not allow you to create new questions or engage on other questions.

To user the chatter answers functionality, you have to add it to your community as a tab there (or go to that tab in the community you're at). Please see the [Chatter Answers Implementation Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=questions_portal_setup_about.htm&language=en_US)

[image]